# Pull data from SimpleDB to iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to familiarize myself with both SimpleDB and iOS. I have a situation where I have created a database with simpleDB and I would like to pull the items into iOS and populate.

How would I do about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`Sample Code & Libraries`

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-SimpleDB/4083

`See more details at`

http://simpledb.ios-aws.com/home/AwsOperations/BatchPutAttributes

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS:

https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/

The SDK offers support for SimpleDB and includes a sample for interacting with a SimpleDB domain:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8829919029640036

Comment: That page lists a ton of Amazon services, but doesn't say that they do anything with SimpleDB.

Comment: This answer was written before the new v2 SDK was launched, but even the v2 SDK does support SimpleDB, even if it is not advertised on the marketing pages. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/SimpleDB

Comment: Is this not really true anymore? It seems like the new MobileHub and all the iOS Swift sample code use DynamoDB exclusively.

Comment: @JamesToomey SimpleDB is still supported in the SDK. See [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSSimpleDB).

Comment: Thanks for the link; the previous link appears to be dead ("SimpleDB" changed to "AWSSimpleDB"). Will the code ever be translated to Swift? Not a big deal because I can tackle it, it's just always nice when it's already done for you!

Comment: My question about a Swift translation isn't a laziness thing--it's more that it feels like SimpleDB might be "technically" supported but isn't the preferred tool. All the latest-and-greatest iOS & MobileHub samples really push DynamoDB over SimpleDB and RDS. SimpleDB doesn't even appear on the AWS Console--I didn't even know it existed until I happened across the name by accident, so you don't get the "try this cool thing out!" vibe at all--more like it's the backlot last year's model.

Comment: @JamesToomey I cannot comment on a Swift port of the SDK. As to the status of SimpleDB, we do recommend that new customers use DynamoDB instead, but the support is still there for legacy reasons.

Comment: @BobKinney, I don't see any iOS samples for RDS (Relational Database Service) at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios. Is this not supported?

Comment: @JamesToomey The RDS API is for managing the database, not getting data from it. Because it does not make much sense to create/start databases from a mobile client, it's not supported. If you want to connect to your RDS instance, you should use a client for the type of database (MySQL, Oracle, etc).

Comment: @BobKinney, Okay, got it, thanks. Sorry to keep bothering you about this, just trying to wrap my head around it all.